# Accessing data from httparty response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using httparty I can get the following response:

```
puts Representative.find_by_zip(46544).inspect
```

-->

```
{"results"=>[{"name"=>"Joe Donnelly", "district"=>"2", "office"=>"1218 Longworth", "phone"=>"(202) 225-3915", "link"=>"http://donnelly.house.gov/", "state"=>"IN"}]
```

source of the example: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/07/29/it-s-an-httparty-and-everyone-is-invited/

but I fail to access the data, for example:

`Representative.find_by_zip(46544).inspect["name"]` returns `nil`

How can I access individual elements of this response?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Object#inspect` returns a string, not a hash. You want this:

```
Representative.find_by_zip(46544)['results'][0]['name']
```

This is what's going on: `Representative#find_by_zip` returns a Hash with just one index:  `'results'`. The item at `'results'` is an array, which in this case only contains one element, so we use `[0]` to get the first (and only) element. That element is itself a hash that has the `'name'` key, which points to the name of the first (and only) representative returned.

When you have complex hashes and arrays it's sometimes useful to format it in a more readable way to figure out how to get at the data you want:

```
{ "results" => [
    { "name"      => "Joe Donnelly",
      "district"  => "2",
      "office     => "1218 Longworth",
      "phone"     => "(202) 225-3915",
      "link"      => "http://donnelly.house.gov/",
      "state"     => "IN"
    }
  ]
}
```

That should make it more clear what's inside what here.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

**To Access the individual elements, You can use:-**

If the response is JSON:- 
*You can use:-*

```ruby
response.parsed_response["key"]
```

If your response is a string then, you can use:-

```ruby
data = JSON.parse(resp.body)
```

The response type depends, on the content type you are setting while requesting the data:-

```ruby
 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
```

If you don't set the content type it returns response as string.